Unable to get CAN network to show up in Docker Container despite passing the --network host parameter
# Use the official ROS 2 Humble base image
FROM ros:humble-ros-base

# Set up workspace
WORKDIR /walle_dt

# Install necessary dependencies, including net-tools, can-utils, and ping
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3-rosdep python3-colcon-common-extensions nano \
    iproute2 net-tools can-utils iputils-ping && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip

# Initialize rosdep
RUN rm -f /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
RUN rosdep init
RUN rosdep update

# Create ROS 2 workspace directories
RUN mkdir -p /walle_dt/walle_dt_ros2_ws/src

WORKDIR /walle_dt
WORKDIR /walle_dt/walle_dt_ros2_ws

# Initialize workspace (this builds it in the correct directory)
RUN /bin/bash -c "source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash && colcon build"

# Source ROS in the bashrc for new terminals
RUN echo "source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc

ENV PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python3

# Create entrypoint for workspace
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]



above is my docker file and below is the script i run to start the container
#!/bin/bash

# Define the Docker image name
IMAGE_NAME="walle_dt_ros2"

# Define the local directory to mount
LOCAL_WS="/home/wall-e/WALL-E/ros2_ws"

# Build the Docker image
docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .

# Run the Docker container with the mounted workspace, privileged mode, and host network
docker run -it --rm --privileged --network host \
  --cap-add=ALL \
  -v "/home/wall-e/WALL-E/ros2_ws:/walle_dt/walle_dt_ros2_ws" walle_dt_ros2 /bin/bash

when using ifconfig on the host I can see the CAN network is up and running but when I do this in the running container it is not present. Also not seeing wlan or eth0 but the container does have access to the internet so figure the container is using some bridge for those.
also worth noting this is running on a raspi 5

Are you using Docker Desktop, or another similar VM-based setup?  If you're running a privileged container with unrestricted permissions and host networking, are you actually using any of Docker's core isolation features; would it be easier to just run this program directly on the host?

Document not just what you installed docker on, but how you installed it, including whether it is running rootless, in a vm, docker desktop, or as a snap.

im running rootless, installed it using this script
(curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh)
then it recommended a command to run for rootless
cant run locally because of a dependency issue thats not compatible with raspi os and it just makes sense to have it in the docker with the rest of the development stuff
